# What should be the better way to store images or files to folder in laravel application

Tags: laravel, file

I am doing a project using Laravel. Now, I have to store `customers`, `users` etc images both in the database and application folder. There are two ways to store `images` or `files` in laravel application.

1. Inside `public` folder I can store.
2. Another one is, inside `storage/app/public`

From these two ways, what should be better to do this. Would someone suggest me please?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's not an *enormous* difference, but in general, it's better to put things in `storage/app/public`.

This allows you to give Laravel write permissions to the `storage` folder, while leaving its permissions on `public` as read-only. This is a bit more secure.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, if your files need to be publicly available you it is recommended you use the laravel "Public Disk" which exposes `yoursite.com/storage/` as a symbolic link to `your_app/storage/app/public`.

You can activate the public disk by running

```
php artisan storage:link
```

If files uploaded do not need to be directly accessed via the web, it is recommended that you use the "Local Driver" - these files are kept securely inside `your_app/storage/app` - one level up from the public folder and are not directly accessible by a web browser.

You are of course free to create any file structure in these directories as you need for your customers etc.

The `Storage` class helper is extremely useful.